# Can Javascript break XSL transformation ? XSL 1.0

Tags: javascript, xslt

I use XSLT for a few month now and i'm used to include js files or to use `<script></script>` tags directly in the XSL.

but today something that i don't understand is happening, this is my main template :

```
<xsl:template name="content">
      <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-heading" style="padding-top: 15px;">
          <div class="jumbotron" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <h1 class="text-center">Fiche auteur</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
         ...
         ...
         </div>
     </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Everything works well but when I add some javascript, html is not generated, like if the javascript is breaking the xsl transformation

```
<xsl:template name="content">
    <script type=text/javascript>
       $(document).ready(function() {
           console.log("ko"); <-- output ko in a blanc page -->
       });
     </script>
     <div class="panel">
         <div class="panel-heading" style="padding-top: 15px;">
             <div class="jumbotron" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
                 <h1 class="text-center">Fiche auteur</h1>
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="panel-body">
          ...
          ...
          </div>
     </div>
</xsl:template>
```

So my question is pretty simple, is it possible for javascript to break an XSL transformation and if it can, how can I prevent it ?

I tryied to export it in a file, using `<script src="my-path/myFile.js"></script>` but it the same problem.

**UPDATE**
From suggestions of comment and response, script updated to :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       <![CDATA[
           $(document).ready(function() {
           console.log("ko");
          });
       ]]>
    </script>
```

No changes, it still display ko in a blanc page, and the good html when removed.

Comment: XSLT is XML so you have to use XML syntax and quote attributes properly, so correct `<script type=text/javascript>` to `<script type="text/javascript">` and chances are the problem is fixed. But we would really need to see a minimal but complete sample and any error message you get.

Comment: That was a error from me in the creation of the question. That would have been nice that it was the solution !

Comment: Well, construct a minimal but complete sample allowing us to reproduce the problem, explain in detail whether you are using XSLT client- or server-side and tell us which browser shows a blank page, and we have something to work with. I have tried to incorporate your snippet into a minimal sample at http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2015120401.xml respectively http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2015120401.xsl but testing with IE 11, Chrome 47, Firefox 42 and Edge on Windows does not show any problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you *must* use an inline script, use a CDATA section for it. I'd strongly recommend using an external file (`<script src="..."></script>` instead, though.

Also, don't use XML comment syntax inside the script body, but JS comment syntax.

```
<xsl:template name="content">
    <script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[
       $(document).ready(function() {
           console.log("ko"); // output ko in a blanc page
       });
    ]]></script>
    <!-- ... -->
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: No i don't have to use inline script, but both ways don't work properly.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what *"it still display ko in a blanc page"* means. Make a screenshot, if it's too difficult to explain.